# How to bypass "Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation."?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, urlloader, urlrequest

I have created an advent calendar for the blog of a friend, and to fetch/get/download the gifts of each day, the flash animation requests a file located at "http://domain.com/folder/etcetc/gifts.php".

While creating the file in Flash CS4 and trying it out, I never got the error. But when I try to launch the `.swf` manually, I get this error:

> Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation.
>
> The following local application on your computer or network:
>
> C:\location\file.swf
>
> is trying to communicate with this Internet-enabled location:
>
> domain.com
>
> To let this aplication communicate with the Internet, click Settings. 
>   You must restart the application after changing your settings.

Is there any way to bypass this, or any other method I can use to stop this error from showing? I'm currently using `URLLoader` and `URLRequest`, is there any better/faster/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that this problem wasn't relevant after all, as it only occurred when I opened the `.swf` locally. When I uploaded it to my webserver and tried to access the flash file with my webbrowser, it worked just as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 5):

you must add the swf file location (just c:\ or exact path) to the trusted list in [Adobe FlashPlayer Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) in order to allow a local swf connect the internet

Answer (score 0):

lol.  that's funny.  Try using Flash CS4 to create a mac/pc projector.  Or create an AIR file.  Running an item through Flash Player will have all sorts of issues with rights.  The projector removes these necessities.

Answer (score 0):

SWF files were showing the same message on a webpage and browser so I changed the flash player version in my HTML code to 9.0.45.0. Now it works fine!